# Redirecting customers based on the product they select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a shopping cart and depending on the `product.id`, I need to send a potential customer to a corresponding URL (the form action URL).

Here's some of my HTML:

```
<div id="product-pricing">
  <form name="product_form" action="/cart/add">
    <div class="single-item">
      <p class="price">$9.99</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="00001">
      <input class="btn" type="submit" name="add" id="add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can I somehow read the `value` field using some JavaScript with or without jQuery (which I will include in the header section) and then, inside the code, have the outcome defined as something like:

```
if id="00001" the form action="http://domain.com/page1.php"
if id="00002" the form action="http://domain.com/page2.php"
if id="00003" the form action="http://domain.com/page3.php"
if id="00004" the form action="http://domain.com/page4.php"
if id="00005" the form action="http://domain.com/page5.php"
```

So, if a user orders id="00002" and clicks the "Add to cart" button, he will go to `http://domain.com/page2.php`. Or, if a user picks product id "00004" and clicks the "Add to cart" button, he will go straight to `http://domain.com/page4.php`.

In short, I need to redirect a potential customer to a different page depending on the product they order. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just have page.php accept an id parameter? You could set the method of your form to `get` and submitting the form would lead to something like `page.php?id=00001`.

Comment: Thank you Alfredo for your comment, the environment I am on does not accept PHP code, it only works with javascript :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<script>
var yourid = $("input[name='id']").val();
if (yourid  = "someid") $("form[name='product_form']").attr("action","your_link");
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having an "aha" moment ! Thank you, user2853290

Thanks a lot, will play around with that

Comment: It's safe to assume that there will only be one product_form on the page?

Comment: Alfredo: yes - just one product on a product page

Comment: Jozin, Can I have your skype ID? Can we make friend?